# How can I use Numerical Python with Python 2.6

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I'm forced to upgrade to Python 2.6 and am having issues using Numerical Python ([NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy)) with Python 2.6 in Windows.  I'm getting the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from numpy.core.numeric import array,dot,all
  File "C:\svn\svn_urbansim\UrbanSimDev\Builds\working\urbansim\Tools\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    import core
  File "C:\svn\svn_urbansim\UrbanSimDev\Builds\working\urbansim\Tools\Python26\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: Module use of python25.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

It appears that the existing module is trying to use the `python25.dll` file.  Is there any way I can tell it to use the `python26.dll` file instead without modifying the source code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How did you install it?  NumPy doesn't currently have a Python 2.6 binary.

If you have [LAPACK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK)/[ATLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatically_Tuned_Linear_Algebra_Software)/[BLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms), etc. and a development environment you should be able to compile numpy from sources.  Otherwise I think you're stuck with using Python 2.5 on Windows if you need NumPy.

The next version of NumPy should have a 2.6 binary, and it's likely to be out within the next month or so.

[Edit]: It appears that a pygame developer created a NumPy 1.2.1 binary for Python 2.6 on Windows, available [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg14552.html).

Answer (score 3):

[NumPy 1.3.0 is available for Python 2.6 now](http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=1369&filename=numpy-1.3.0-win32-superpack-python2.6.exe&a=35708818).